# Spring Kafka Manual Immediate Acknowledgement along with SeekToCurrentErrorHandler

Tags: spring-kafka

I am referring this answer:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728833/seektocurrenterrorhandler-deadletterpublishingrecoverer-is-not-handling-deseria#:~:text=It%20works%20fine%20for%20me%20(note%20that%20Boot%20will%20auto-configure%20the%20error%20handler)..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728833/seektocurrenterrorhandler-deadletterpublishingrecoverer-is-not-handling-deseria#:%7E:text=It%20works%20fine%20for%20me%20(note%20that%20Boot%20will%20auto-configure%20the%20error%20handler)..).

Can we add manual immediate acknowledgement like below:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "so56728833", topics = "so56728833")
public void listen(Foo in, Acknowledgment ack {
    System.out.println(in);
    if (in.getBar().equals("baz")) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Test retries");
    }
    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

I want this because of following scenario:
Let's say I have processed 100 messages, now while processing next 10 records, my consumer gets down after processing 4 messages. In this case, rebalance will get triggered and this 4 messages will be processed again because I have not committed my offset.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use manual immediate here - you can also use `AckMode.RECORD` and the container will automatically commit each offset after the record has been processed.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#committing-offsets